# How do I call the environmental variables from within a Twilio Function?

Tags: twilio

If you want to call a Twilio environmental variable from within a Twilio function, you can do it like this.

```
context.myVariableName
```

I didn't see the answer on Stack Exchange, I hope it helps.  To set the environmental variable, it is done from "Configure" in the Functions menu.

Comment: A question with its own answer baked in. Fabulous!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is correct, though not really a question. You can find out all about [how the environment for a Twilio Function is constructed in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions/environment#context).

Notably, in the function signature `exports.handler = function(context, event, callback)` the following is the case:

`context` contains:

- all environment variables that you set in the Configure section

and, if you have "Enable ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN" checked in the Configure section:

- ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN set to the relevant values for your account
- a function, `getTwilioClient()`, which will return an API client from the [Twilio module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) authenticated with your account sid and auth token

`event` then contains:

- query and body parameters from `GET` or `POST` requests

and `callback` is a function that should be invoked once you are finished processing the request and would like to complete execution. If there was an error in execution, pass that error as the first argument of `callback`. Otherwise, pass `null` as the first argument and the response you want to return as the second argument.

As I said, [this is all in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions/environment), but I hope it helps if you were missing something.

Comment: is it possible to change the value of environment variable from the twilio function? i.e. modify the env variable in one in function invocation and read the updated value from another. (let me just mention here that i dont want to use twilio Sync because it solves very different problem. my usecase can be solved simply by a KV type storage also)

Comment: No, as far as I’m aware the environment variables are constants unless you change them in the config in the Twilio console. If you need a key value store then you should use a key value store, whether that is Sync, Redis or something else.